# What is the recommended play order of the Batman: Arkham series?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I've got all the games on PC.

- Arkham Asylum GOTY
- Arkham City GOTY
- Arkham Origins
- Arkham Origins Blackgate
- Arkham Knight

What is the recommended play order for these games? In order of release date, or chronological order?

If chronological then what would the best order be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory, both orders work in their own way.

However, I think it's better to play them in release order, as their storytelling is quite independent and it's pretty easy to follow the timeline in their stories.

The big advantage of the release order is the steady improvement and expansion of game mechanics. If you play *Origins* first, *Asylum* will be a step back.

Despite this, *Arkham Knight* is harder to sort chronology, since it includes a few story DLC's exploring both the past and future.

**TL;DR:** Play the games in release order. DLC always after the main game, except the *Harley Quinn Story Pack* - play that before *Arkham Knight*.

Comment: I'd also add blackgate after origins, as I think they were released on the same day.